# Is it possible to expand `include(foo.cmake)`'s content in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I would like to get the "expanded CMakeLists.txt" that replace each `include(foo.cmake)` with corresponding content. Don't know if it is possible.

For example, I have `CMakeLists.txt` with contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(hello)
include(hello.cmake)
message(STATUS "***** hello_str is ${hello_str}")
```

and `hello.cmake` with contents:

```
set(hello_str "Hello, World")
```

I would get an expaned CMakeLists.txt with contents (yeah, just like C/C++'s preprocess)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(hello)
set(hello_str "Hello, World") ##!!
message(STATUS "***** hello_str is ${hello_str}")
```

Is that possible? And how?

---

OK, due to people in the comments really didn't understand, I have to make it **more clear**.

In the cross-compilation stage, the commonly usage is:

```sh
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=qnx-aarch64.toolchain.cmake
cmake --build .
```

But actually the `qnx-aarch64.toolchain.cmake` contains one line:

```
include(linux-aarch64.toolchain.cmake)
```

Thus, people have to have both `qnx-aarch64.toolchain.cmake` and `linux-aarch64.toolchain.cmake`, instead only one `qnx-aarch64.toolchain.cmake` file.

What I expected is only one `qnx-aarch64.toolchain.cmake` file to finish the cross-compilation.

@fabian You don't understand my question and keep telling very simple stuffs and assumes I don't know those stuffs.

Comment: Feels like an XY problem, to be frank. What do you believe it will solve if you were able to?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I would like to **keep** standalone some_platform-toolchain.cmake files, while my college maintains several toolchain.cmake files that **include** some "common" or "base" files, I would like to generate them.

Comment: Okay, and? Files being `include`ed can `include` others too, even if it isn't preprocessing. Instead of re-iterating what you **want** with **bold** font, I suggest you describe what problem you ran into when breaking the base file apart.

Comment: You should not include toolchain files **at all** (assuming we're refering to cmake toolchain files here). Those are relevant during the initial configuration and hardcoding them into a cmake files (whether by copy&paste or by other means) severely limits the reuseablility. If you're talking about "helper functions" they would be better off in a cmake module, see [this cppcon presentation](https://youtu.be/IZXNsim9TWI). One way or another I don't see any benefit in copy&pasting the content of the included file there. Also let's not ignore the fact that the logic could be changed by doing this.

Comment: @fabian What I mean is "the xx-platform.toolchain.cmake" is including another "base.toolchain.cmake". I never said "include xx-platform.toolchain.cmake in CMakeLists.txt".

Comment: @fabian Why you response with "You should not include toolchain files" ? What I said is my college is doing that including stuff, it is not me.

Comment: A toolchain file should be added via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` cache variable or via `--toolchain` command line option. Tollchain files are supposed to be used to specify a set of compilers and related settings the user of the project can specify; it's not something that's supposed to be "hardwired" to the project since this severely limits reuseability. Perhaps you're just using the wrong terminology though...

Comment: @fabian I of course know A toolchain file should be added via CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE. You don't have to repeat it not relevant stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible?

No. CMake 3.22 (the current at time of writing) and below do not provide this feature.